# Chef Nessus Agent Install

Tags: ansible, chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen, nessus

I am trying to write a cookbook to download and install Nessus Agent found here:

https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus-agents

But am having trouble due to an explicit download url not being provided, and the requirement of accepting the license agreement.

I am using `windows_package` to try and install it.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar thing with Ansible. For now I'm working around it by keeping the install package in my Ansible files and uploading it to the target for deployment.

Not the most efficient approach. But does also ensure we've accepted the license agreement prior to download, which is probably what Tenable want.